# Can a deep learning model learn to understand/interpret the logical sentences?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, language-models

I don't know what the development in NLP has gone so far. I'm curious about whether my machine can answer me following question?

"Today is Sunday. I'll finish my project in two days. What will be day of week when I finish my Project?"

So, as a human beings, we can understand and interpret this question right? Clearly the answer should be "Tuesday". But can a trained deep model answer such questions?

If there is any such open source chatbot developed, then can anyone mention it please? Or, please mention which is a very good Open Source project using NLP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on question-answering natural language processing algorithms, but it is a very dynamic area of research, and you can easily Google it, to find many blog entries and papers on recent advancements in this area.

Since I don't have access to any such algorithm, let me use example of text-generating algorithm based on the, state of art, GPT-2 model (it can be also adapted for question-answering as far as I know). You can [check it online](https://talktotransformer.com/). Below you can see prompts (bolded) and the generated text that I've chosen from several attempts.

> **Today is Sunday. I'll finish my project in two days. I will finish my Project at** the end of the week.
>
> Inbetween, I'll be working on my Monday Job. [...]

or another one

> **Today is Sunday. I'll finish my project in two days. I will finish my Project at** 5 a.m. on Monday, October 21st.
>
> How do you deal with changes in time and personality?

As you can see, both generated texts show that the model *does not understand* the prompt and the idea of time. While such algorithms are pretty good at what they are doing, they are still pretty dumb and what they learn, is they memorize and learn to find patterns in the text, to complete the sentence (or answer, that's the same task, just you need different data to train the model).